# Tomcat 7.0.33 JAVA_OPTS configuration

Tags: tomcat7, jmx, remote-access

I want to use JMX to monitoring tomcat and ActiveMQ with a remote connection.

For activeMQ I added this in JAVA_OPTS in startup.bat:

```
JAVA_OPTS=
-Dwebconsole.type=properties \
-Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616 \
-Dwebconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/ jmxrmi
```

When i'm starting the tomcat server and ActiveMQ, in Jconsole i can connect to url :

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://x.x.x.x:1099/jmxrmi
```

For tomcat monitoring i added:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote ^
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9004 ^
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false ^
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false ^
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x
```

Then, when i'm trying to connect to url `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://x.x.x.x:9004/jmxrmi` in Jconsole,the connection fail.
I tried with Netbeans (who seems to use catalina.bat rather than startup.bat) and moved the java_opts from startup.bat to catalina.bat and here the logs when I start the server:

```
'-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.33"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.33"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
ou externe, un programme ex‚cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
'-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex‚cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

Sorry for the french stuff, the important part says that -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote is not recognize as an internal or external command.

Jconsole debug output:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.117.31; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:357)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:226)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:354)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:314)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:295)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.117.31; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:118)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:203)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1924)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1891)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:274)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.117.31; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:114)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 15 more
```

I left the activeMQ part in startup.bat and I still can connect to it. I really don't know where is the problem... If someone can help me

Comment: I solved the problem `...is not recognize as an internal or external command` adding `set CATALINA_OPTS=` before each parameter without quote. So Tomcat seems to starting up correctly, but I still cannot access to `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://x.x.x.x:9004/jmxrmi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the problem and now can connect the jConsole to the port 9004.
Here's how I configured catalina.bat:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9004 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x
```

No "enter", no quote, I specified `true` to the first parameter, and all in only one CATALINA_OPTS declaration.

Hope it can be useful